# Transparent picture in ImageButton does not display transparency

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my transparent image:

[image]

But when I apply it to my app, the image not transparent, as shown below:

[image]

Why would the following code produce this behaviour?

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/back"/>
```

Activity:

```
ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Back();
    }
});
```

Comment: iirc you'd also have to set something in the img btn property to have a void background

Comment: can we see the whole code ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya see my update

Comment: @Razgriz set what?

Comment: whole code i mean the whole activity it is some other element affection your button

Comment: see my update again, there's no special in my code

Comment: @E-Place Try to make your `Image Button's` background as `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.

Comment: your image is .png or .jpeg?

Comment: Try to use `android:background="#00000000"`.

Comment: see my answer and you should have .png image (without background)

Comment: @E-Place : Use imageview instead of button

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini png

Comment: @E-Place did you check with my last update?

Comment: i am asking about your activity xml @E-Place.. Please let me see it.. I am sure there a problem in that you must be having `activity_main.xml` or something I want to see it..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have try `android:background="@null"`but it's not have changes for me

so i try to **clean project** and **rebuild project** and then **remove my app from phone** and it's work :) Thanks to other who try help me your answer is really help me :)

and this my final code

```
<ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/back"
                        android:src="@drawable/back"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below line in your ImageButton:

```
android:background="@null"
android:src="YOUR_IMAGE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `android:background = "@null"`

```
  <ImageButton 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_action_exit"
  android:background="@null"/>
```

put your `drawable` name instead of `ic_action_exit`.

this should give `transparent background`.

> Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

> Screenshot 2

[image: screenshot2]

> My Image
>
> [image: back_icon]

Comment: how see my screenshot. it's working. you need have the .png format img

Comment: Yes, it may not work. Because your image contains black color. Try to use white color instead of black and check again.

Comment: @SathishKumarJ but not for me. my image is png and without background like you see in my image above

Comment: @Dhruv i think there's no contain black color

Comment: I can clearly see black logout button. Anyway, let us wait to confirm @E-Place, that it is working or not.

Comment: @SathishKumarJ maybe my image is error? can I try with your image back button?

Comment: sure, i'll upload image . wait  a minute

Comment: check my icon and let me it's work or not for you @ Dhruv and @ E-Place

Comment: Did u tried with my back icon? @ Dhruv and @ E-Place

Comment: thanks ^^ but that's solved when i clean and rebuild project and remove my ap from my phone

Comment: kindly accept my answer. then only others can easily find the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<ImageButton
  android:layout_width="30dp"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:id="@+id/back"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:src="@drawable/back" 
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

if it does not work, try setting a background to another color (just to make sure that the src image  is pointing to the correct drawable)

edit: also remove all tints if you have them, to see if it affects the results.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**you are use the direct drawable instead of src**

```
  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/back"

   />
```

> **Note**:  if Your back image is white than should be your main layout or back ImageButton back layout background not white....